# WPF: How to detect text trimming with TextBlock and multiple lines of text

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a TextBlock object in my WPF application and as the text content changes, I need to adjust the font size so that the text is never cut off and the entire text is visible.

From another post, I tried using the following XAML to resize the font but this doesn't seem to work.

```
<Viewbox StretchDirection="DownOnly" Stretch="Uniform" Margin="20,20,20,30" >
        <TextBlock Name="TextBlock_tb"
                   MaxHeight="60"
                   MaxWidth="180"
                   FontFamily="Arial" 
                   Background="LightBlue"
                   TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                   Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua." 
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                   VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </Viewbox>
```

I've also tried to determine if the "CharacaterEllipsis" is showing, but the method from again another post, only seems to work when wrapping is not used.

Is there a feasible way to automatically adjust the font size to allow best fit of the text in the TextBlock area?  I know this is possible, but the solution eludes me. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you might need some more constraints to make the problem better defined. If the font, height and width can all change then there are a lot of ways to solve the problem: like one way would be to always shrink the text. I can see that maybe the height could vary, but not the height and the width, that would be odd. And you probably want to vary the height only at certain font sizes. Make sense?